# Include a PHP file located in the home directory in a module

Tags: files

How can I include a PHP file located in my Drupal's home directory from a module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drupal 7 defines the constant `DRUPAL_ROOT`, which contains the name of the directory where Drupal is installed. It is used from Drupal functions, such as [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) in a way similar to the following one:

```
if (function_exists('drupal_get_path')) {
  $file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', $module) . "/$name.$type";
  if (is_file($file)) {
    require_once $file;
    return $file;
  }
}
```

In your case, you should use the following code:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . "/$filename";
```

The variable `$filename` contains the name of the file to load.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well, according my test is not needed indicate any path, just with the name of your file that is in your home directory. For example I have a file called `testfile.php` in my home directory, then from my module inside `sites/all/modules` I can use:

```
include ('testfile.php');
```

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I would use API [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_load_include/6)</del>.

**Edit** : This API is meant for including PHP file located in module's directory.

Comment: You cannot use `module_load_include()` because the function looks for the file in a module's directory. The OP is asking about a file that is in the directory where Drupal is installed (what the OP calls "Drupal's home directory").